# ASP.net help rewriting simple URL

Tags: c#, url-rewriting

```
<rewrite url="~/Blog" to="~/Blog.aspx" processing="stop"/>
```

This doesn't work, it only seems to work if I define a replacement filename as well... How do I make it so that

http://www.mysite.com/Blog

Goes to:

http://www.mysite.com/Blog.aspx

Comment: _See [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)_

Comment: You have been here long enough to learn how to format code, in particular XML. Indent 4 spaces.

Comment: See [Scott Guthrie's Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: @Luke thanks, I was just missing the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" attribute in web.config

Comment: no problem, reposted comment as answer if you want to close question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Scott Guthrie's Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

With IIS 6.0 (Windows XP and Windows Server 2003), you can't do this with the usual configuration.  IIS looks for a file extension to route the URL to determine which of the installed engines (classic ASP, ASP.Net, PHP, etc.) the request should get routed to.  When there's no extension, IIS looks in the corresponding folder (virtual or real) for a default document, like default.aspx or index.htm, etc.

With IIS 7, you can use Integrated mode to get the behavior you want.  With IIS 6, you can still do it by specially configuring it to route all URLs to ASP.Net, regardless of extension.  For efficiency, you may want to refine it so that static files like images are not routed to ASP.Net.  How to do this is explained here: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

Consider using MVC routing. If you're using .NET 4 it's even easier. All you have to do is reference `System.Web.Routing` and then in the global.asax file you can do `routes.MapPageRoute("Blog Route", "Blog", "~/Blog.aspx");`

Helpful references:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx (.net 4)
- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx (.net 4)
- https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx (.net 3.5)